# Preventing entire JOINed MYSQL query from failing when one field is missing within a WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, variables, field, join

I am doing a couple of joins with a variable in the WHERE clause. I'm not sure if I am doing everything as efficiently as I could, or even using the best practices but my issue is that half my tables have data for when **tableC.type=500**, and the other half don't resulting in the entire query failing.

```
SELECT tableA.value1 , tableB.value2, tableC.value3 FROM tableA  
JOIN tableB ON  tableB.id=tableA.id
JOIN tableC ON  tableC.id=tableB.id
WHERE tableA.category=$var && tableC.type=500;
```

What I would like to happen is to still get **tableA.value1** and **tableB.value2** even if there is *no field* in tableC with a **type=500**.
any thoughts? i'm totally stumped as how to approach this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT tableA.value1 , tableB.value2, tableC.value3 FROM tableA  
JOIN tableB ON  tableB.id=tableA.id
LEFT JOIN tableC ON  tableC.id=tableB.id AND tableC.type=500
WHERE tableA.category=$var;
```

[INNER] JOIN (which you have) joins only if the values exist;

LEFT JOIN returns NULL for tableC columns if no matching row in tableC is found.

I think it's necessary to move the tableC condition(s) into the `ON` clause when using a LEFT JOIN, as `WHERE` would filter out the NULL values (since tableC.type IS NULL != 500).

Comment: ohh fabulous, yes I tried LEFT JOIN but I didn't know I could put conditions after the     ON clause

Answer (score 0):

Try a `LEFT JOIN`